$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^k} dx$
I wanted to evaluate the following series:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{1}{a+kb}$$
Where $a,b \in R$.
After some manipulation(taking $1/a$ out and writing the general term of the sum as an integral from 0 to 1), I got that the series is equal to the following integral:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^k} dx$$
However I have no idea how to proceed from here on. I tried gamma and beta  functions but they did not work , because the thing is $k \in R$, not $k \in Z$.
Is there any closed form of this integral as a function of k? And Also as a sidenote can we evaluate the sum given above in some other way?

In general, this is unknown. It can be phrased in terms of the Lerch phi function, of which some functional identities are known, but it's really just naming your series, not evaluating it.

The sum does not depend on $k,$ but the integral does. Seems like you missed something.

This is a sum that can be likely expressed with something such as the Hurwitz zeta or Dirichlet eta functions, but has no elementary closed form.

Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see meta

This question is a megaduplicate: Values of $\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{dt}{1+t^n}}$, Evaluate $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^m}dx$ for $m>0 $, etc.

@AnneBauval Sorry, I did not know of this.

Next time you can use Approach$0$: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_0%5E1%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2Bx%5Ek%7D%20dx%24&p=1
